# Change Color Swatches in Bootflat

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootflat

I'm using [Bootflat](https://github.com/bootflat) in my project and i want to use color swatches of `bootflat` but i do not  know how to changes swatches.

Comment: @Vector i cant find any themes on [flatthemes.com](http://www.flatthemes.com)

Comment: Precisely, same problem here.

Comment: I have the same Problem... But the answers aren't helpful :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The swatch colors exist as variables in the SASS global partial file.

eg:

```
$bluejeans-dark:              #4A89DC !default;
$bluejeans-light:             #5D9CEC !default;
```

you can use these variables in any part of the boot flat SASS project as global or even single use.

eg:

```
primary-color:$bluejeans-dark;
```

or

```
header { background:$bluejeans-light:}
```

Of course the Bootflat project would require an update using your chosen SASS tool

Answer (score 1):

Follow the [quick start](https://github.com/bootflat/bootflat.github.io#quick-start) instructions, alter the colors in the `_global.scss` file, then run `grunt`